# Rails 3: Where are Javascript :defaults defined after running "rails g jquery:install"?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I just installed jQuery 1.4.4 with Rails 3 as described [here](https://github.com/indirect/jquery-rails).

I do have the following line in `views/layouts/application.html.erb`:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
```

However, in `config/application.rb` the following line is still commented:

```
# config.action_view.javascript_expansions[:defaults] = ...
```

If so, where does Rails defines what `:defaults` means in `javascript_include_tag :defaults` ?

(My application works fine. I just want to understand where `:defaults` is defined.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the jquery-rails gem you've required. https://github.com/indirect/jquery-rails/blob/master/lib/jquery-rails.rb

`rails g jquery:install` just puts the jquery .js files into public/javascripts (and removes prototype).

Comment: Actually, the javascript_expansion for `:defaults` happens in the gem's railtie: https://github.com/indirect/jquery-rails/blob/master/lib/jquery/rails/railtie.rb

Answer (score 5):

I installed jQuery support using the gem as described [here](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs]), and ran the jquery:install generator.  That installed the necessary .js files, but it did -not- automatically cause them to be included in the HTML generated by

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
```

To get that to generate the correct HTML, I had to follow the last instruction in the Manual Installation section and manually change "%w()" to "%w(jquery rails)" on the

```
config.action_view.javascript_expansions[:defaults] = %w()
```

line in my config/application.rb file, after which, everything began working properly.

If it makes any difference, I had created my application using the --skip-prototype option in anticipation of using jQuery instead of Prototype.